# How to mock Firebase Functions HttpCallableResult when return value is used

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, unit-testing

I just start using Firebase Callable Functions in my Flutter app. Previously I had been using the standard https `onRequest` variant for which mocking the return value was very easy because they simply return an `http.Response`. Callable functions, on the other hand, return an `HttpsCallableResult` which is less straight forward because there is only a `data getter` available.

I need to be able to use the return value in my which is what is complicating this. Here is how I'm trying to mock the call such that I can control the return value as well as the error.

**My mocking code**

```
final functions = MockFirebaseFunctions();
when(functions.httpsCallable("generateMatch")).thenAnswer((invocation) {
  HttpsCallable response = MockHttpsCallable();
  return response;
});

when(functions.httpsCallable("generateMatch").call()).thenAnswer((invocation) {
  HttpsCallableResult response = MockHttpsCallableResult();

  when(response.data).thenReturn({"statusCode": 200});
  
  return Future.value(response);
});
```

**Error**

```
FakeUsedError: 'httpsCallable'
No stub was found which matches the argument of this method call:
httpsCallable('generateMatch', {options: null})

A fake object was created for this call, in the hope that it won't be ever accessed.
Here is the stack trace where 'httpsCallable' was called:

#0 new SmartFake mock.dart:245
#1 new _FakeHttpsCallable_5 user_repo_test.mocks.dart:89
#2 MockFirebaseFunctions.httpsCallable user_repo_test.mocks.dart:713
#3 main.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> user_repo_test.dart:514
#4 Declarer.test.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> declarer.dart:215 <asynchronous suspension>
#5 StackZoneSpecification._registerUnaryCallback.<anonymous closure> stack_zone_specification.dart:124 <asynchronous suspension>

However, member 'call' of the created fake object was accessed.
Add a stub for MockFirebaseFunctions.httpsCallable using Mockito's 'when' API.

SmartFake.noSuchMethod mock.dart:242
_FakeHttpsCallable_5.call user_repo_test.mocks.dart:85
main.<fn>.<fn>.<fn>
```

Comment: seems like you did not add the 2nd parameter `{options: null}` when setting up the mock.

Comment: please include the code/source for `MockFirebaseFunctions`

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is pretty clear:

> FakeUsedError: 'httpsCallable'
> No stub was found which matches the argument of this method call:
> httpsCallable('generateMatch', {options: null})

It seems you (or some library?) are calling `httpsCallable('generateMatch', {options: null})` and NOT `httpsCallable('generateMatch')`. Simply add the extra argument to your mock.